# MYSQL - FullText search - Search by partial string

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In fulltext search is there a way to treat a string like a single word?

I'll try to explain myself with an example.

I have my query

```
SELECT id, ragione_sociale
FROM anagrafiche 
WHERE 
MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+eno*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) 
AND country_code="IT"
```

and my results are as expected

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Enoteca del visone |
| 2 | Enoteca Squillari |
| 3 | Enonegozio Paolo |

so, part of the word, and i like it.

But my problem is when my search is with multiple words.

For example "Enoteca Vini"

The following are the records in my database, and the results i expect

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Enoteca Vini & Sapori |
| 2 | Enoteca Vini D'autore |
| 3 | Enoteca Vini e Sapori |
| 4 | Enoteca Vini Sfusi Vin Più |
| 5 | Enoteca Vini Vizi e Virtu |
| **6** | **Enoteca Vinicola Rotondi Sas** |
| 7 | Vinicola Enoteca Vini Sfusi |

But when i execute the query like this

```
SELECT id, ragione_sociale
FROM anagrafiche 
WHERE 
MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+"enoteca vini*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

number 6 isn't in my results, the query consider "vini" as a full word and not as a partial one.

Is there another way or another syntax to obtain my desired result?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you filtering also based on `country_code` in second query ?

Comment: Also, What results you get when you change this line to :

`MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+enoteca vini*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )`
Does that return you expected results ?

Comment: Yes, forgot to copy last AND, but same country code.  With MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+enoteca vini*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ), or  i have too much results. I need "enoteca vini" (or other search) to be treated the same way as a single word if possible

Comment: OK, NO Worries;
`MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+enoteca vini*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )`

Does this (Removing double quotes) return you expected data ?

When we use double quotes for a string in mysql fulltext search; mysql treats that string as a single word / phrase

Comment: Replied the first part in the previous comment. Yes, i need mysql to treat the string as a single word, but, like it's possibile for single word to be reaserched as partial, i need to do it with a string

Comment: Can you use asterik after enoteca with following expression and let me know, whether they match your search.
Here asterik can match to any number of characters.


`MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+"enoteca* vini*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE )`

Comment: It gives me the same result as  ->  MATCH (ragione_sociale) AGAINST ('+"enoteca vini*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE ), it still exclude #6: Enoteca Vinicola. it consider vini a whole word and not partial